# Laravel - Obtener array multidimensional

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

tengo este método el cual tengo que hacer una consulta para obtener unos IDS y sobre estos IDS hago una consulta individual.

El código me funciona, pero tal como me devuelve el array no me és cómodo para tratarlo desde JS.

Yo quiero obtener un array de arrays y obtengo un array de objetos.

```
    public function alimentsByCategory($category_id): JsonResponse
{
    $aliments = AlimentCategory::where('category_id',$category_id)
        ->where('enabled',1)
        ->get();

    $array = [];

    foreach ($aliments as $aliment) {
        $alimentObj = Aliment::where('id',$aliment->id)->get();

        array_push($array, $alimentObj);

    }

    return response()->json($array);
}
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es tal como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito el post , actualizando con las relaciones entre modelos.

En **aliment** tengo esta relación

```
public function categories()
{
    $this->hasMany(AlimentCategory::class);
}
```

En **AlimentCategory** tengo esta relación

```
public function aliment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Aliment::class);
}
```

Comment: Tienes definida la relación entre AlimentCategory y Aliment?

Comment: Si la tengo definida, acabo de editar el post principal.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que es así la relación? ¿"UN Alimento tiene MUCHAS Categorías" y "UNA Categoría pertenece a UN solo Alimento"? No digo que no esté bien... pero generalmente es al revés